# How do I incorporate iAd into my Flash application?

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, iad

I was working on a simple game app using Xcode, but when I saw that image manipulation is much easier using the Flash SDK, I reprogrammed the game using Flash.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to incorporate iAds into my Flash iOS app.  I tried searching on Google, but all I got were references to the ongoing battle between Apple and Adobe.

I appreciate any tips - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a sample for iAds Native Extensions(Introduced newly with AIR 3) that will let you insert iAds in your flash game. You can try http://code.google.com/p/iad-air-ios/

Answer (score 0):

To implement Apple's iAd, I found a nice way using the native extension in Air3.
There are a few tutorials/articles on Native extensions floating around.

Adobe has a page with its Native extensions for download.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

Comment: I believe mskfisher edited it.  Yes, I can confirm the link works now.